# Fatal error: Call to a member function register_handler() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, database-design, wordpress

I have a website in Wordpress and I get an error which is given below:

Fatal error: Call to a member function register_handler() on a non-object in `/home/a2ztaxcorpllp/public_html/wp-includes/media.php` on `line 2003`.

I have uploaded the files successfully with Filezilla to the server in Godaddy but when i try to open my website I got the above error.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing there, but maybe this helps: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-35-error-on-line-944

Comment: Try to copy on the media.php file alone to FTP